# 2D interface question

Tags: interface, grease-pencil, draw-mode

I can create a new file in General, then add a 2D Animation tab to get into 2D.
I also can create a 2D Animation file directly.

What's the difference between these 2 ways?

[image]

[image]

Comment: quite simple, General file will give you piece of tabs that are most useful in General, Sculpt will give you tabs that mostly sculptors use, 2D animation will give you what 2d animators in Blender will probably mostly need, that's all, also If you use 2D animation file, you already have your file prepared for animation with Default Stroke, General is prepared with Default 3D cube, sculpting is prepared with default cubic sphere etc

Comment: @MikoCG This should be posted as an answer, not as a comment...

Comment: I didn't think that such a basic explanation is worth to be an answer... I hoped that someone will give more in deep explanation